# Ansible Python API: how to pass extra vars to playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to use Python API to run some playbooks because I want to integrate it with Flash to enable the web-base control. Here is my playbook(*crondis.yaml*):

```
- hosts: "{{app_name}}-server"
  tasks:
    - name: disable cron
      cron:
        name: "{{app_name|upper}}_MONITOR"
        job: "/{{app_name}}/monitor.sh"
        disabled: yes
```

From cml that can be this way:

```
ansible-playbook --extra-vars="{'app_name': 'newapp'}" crondis.yaml
```

But in the Python API, I'm not seeing any place to add the vars to the play. I checked **Variable_Manager**, **DataLoader** and **PlaybookExecutor** but didn't find any function can add vars to the play.
Please kindly shed a little bit light for me if you have any idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define extra variables by setting `.extra_vars` property, see `ansible-playbook` cli [code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.3/lib/ansible/cli/playbook.py#L123):

```
    # create the variable manager, which will be shared throughout
    # the code, ensuring a consistent view of global variables
    variable_manager = VariableManager()
    variable_manager.extra_vars = load_extra_vars(loader=loader, options=self.options)
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply I was unable to test before today. Yes I tested adding extra_vars to Variable_Manager and it works perfect!

Comment: Here is the code I tried: `variable_manager.extra_vars = {'app_name': 'test'}`

Comment: I am using python3 and I am getting an error with this line `variable_manager.extra_vars = load_extra_vars(loader=loader, options=self.options)`
AttributeError: can't set attribute

Comment: `variable_manager._extra_vars = load_extra_vars(loader=loader, options=self.options)`

This worked for me

Answer (score 4):

You can specify extra variables from within context.CLIARGS. You can specify a file by using `@`.

```
context.CLIARGS = ImmutableDict(connection='local', module_path=['/to/mymodules'], forks=10, become=None,
                            become_method=None, become_user=None, check=False, diff=False,
                            extra_vars={'@/path/to/vars/file', 'key=value'})
```

Comment: I cannot get this to work, even with a simple extra_vars={'key=value'}. The variable is undefined. The cliargs does work but the extra_var does not get updated

Comment: Hi, i think at some point, i got a similar issue, so i did something like this. Modifying manually the state.
`variable_manager = VariableManager(loader=loader, inventory=inventory, version_info=CLI.version_info(gitinfo=False))
state = variable_manager.__getstate__()
for key in _extra_vars:
 state['extra_vars'][key] = _extra_vars[key]
variable_manager.__setstate__(state)`

Comment: I cannot remember exactly why the extra_var was not getting updated. It was something in the parsing order, i think. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using ansible==2.9.6 and seeing the same issue. Followed the procedure mentioned here to update state['extra_vars'] dict and able to pass vars; thanks a lot