# Set extras vars ansible with API

Tags: python, api, ansible

I'm trying to pass the host to the API ansible as extra vars, so I can choose from my list of hosts which one to affect, but the attribute is not being set

I didn't understand how to apply the example below in my code

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45220834/ansible-python-api-how-to-pass-extra-vars-to-playbook)

The documentation is lacking

[View Doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_api.html)

Any suggetions?

Git: [View](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.3/lib/ansible/cli/playbook.py#L123)

> playbook

```
---
- name: Clean memory
  hosts:
    - '{{ affected_hosts }}'
  tasks:
  - command: apt-get clean
```

> run.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys
from ansible import context
from ansible.cli import CLI
from ansible.module_utils.common.collections import ImmutableDict
from ansible.executor.playbook_executor import PlaybookExecutor
from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader
from ansible.inventory.manager import InventoryManager
from ansible.vars.manager import VariableManager
from ansible.errors import AnsibleError, AnsibleParserError, AnsibleUndefinedVariable, AnsibleFileNotFound, AnsibleAssertionError, AnsibleTemplateError
from ansible.plugins.callback import CallbackBase
try:
    import prettytable
    HAS_PRETTYTABLE = True
except ImportError:
    HAS_PRETTYTABLE = False

class ResultsCallback(CallbackBase):
    """ A callback plugin used for performing an action as results come in """
    def __init__(self):
        super(ResultsCallback, self).__init__()
        # Store all failed results
        self.failed = []

class ModuleResultsCollector():

    def run_playbook(self, playbook_path, selectuser, selectpass, extra_vars=None):

        if not os.path.exists(playbook_path):
            print('[INFO] The playbook does not exist: "{0}"'.format(playbook_path))
            sys.exit()

        if not os.path.isfile(host_file):
            print('[INFO] Host file does not exist: "{0}"'.format(host_file))

        else:

            try:

                loader = DataLoader()
                passwords = dict(vault_pass=selectpass)

                context.CLIARGS = ImmutableDict(tags={}, listtags=False, listtasks=False, listhosts=False, syntax=False, connection='ssh',
                                    module_path=None, forks=100, remote_user=selectuser, private_key_file=None,
                                    ssh_common_args=None, ssh_extra_args=None, sftp_extra_args=None, scp_extra_args=None, become=True,
                                    become_method='sudo', become_user=selectuser, verbosity=True, check=False, start_at_task=None)

                inventory = InventoryManager(loader=loader, sources=('/etc/ansible/hosts'))

                variable_manager = VariableManager(loader=loader, inventory=inventory, version_info=CLI.version_info(gitinfo=False))

                variable_manager.extra_vars = {'affected_hosts': 'webserver'}

                pbex = PlaybookExecutor(playbooks=[playbook_path], inventory=inventory, variable_manager=variable_manager, loader=loader, passwords=passwords)

                try:

                    callback = ResultsCallback()
                    pbex._tqm._stdout_callback = callback
                    failed = callback.failed

                    if failed:

                        print('[INFO] Playbook failed: {}'.format(failed[0]))

                    else:

                        pbex.run()
                        print('[INFO] Playbook pass: {} [ok]'.format(playbook_path))

                except AnsibleError as ansError:

                    print('[INFO] Ansible error: {}'.format(ansError))

            except Exception as e:

                print('[INFO]: {} - Failed caused by: {}'.format(playbook_path,e))

selectuser = 'root'
selectpass = 'root'
selectplay = 'ALL_CLEAN_MEMORY_LINUX.yml'
host_file = '/etc/ansible/hosts'

flow = ModuleResultsCollector()
flow.run_playbook('/etc/ansible/playbooks/'+selectplay+'', selectuser, selectpass)
```

> output

```
Failed caused by: can't set attribute
```

> After a lot of research I found that just adding an extras_vars = []
>   tag to content

```
context.CLIARGS = ImmutableDict(tags={}, 
listtags=False, 
listtasks=False, 
listhosts=False, 
extra_vars=[{'affected_hosts':'server-name'}])
```

Comment: (a) this is VERY FAR from an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (b) are you sure you don't want [ansible-runner](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-runner#readme) instead?

Comment: Your suggestion is very valid, I will research more on the subject!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: *"Pass the host to the API ansible as extra vars."*

A: Let's assume the extra variable is a list of hosts *`affected_hosts`*. It's possible to loop this list and create a group of hosts in the first play. Then use it in the second one. For example

```
- name: Create group of affected hosts
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - add_host
        name: "{{ item }}"
        groups: affected_hosts_group
      loop: "{{ affected_hosts }}"

- name: Clean memory
  hosts: affected_hosts_group
  tasks:
    - command: apt-get clean
```

Configure *`extra_vars`* in the script.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion, I was just in doubt, how would you do this, in this section? " variable_manager.extra_vars = {'affected_hosts': 'webserver'} "

Comment: This part generates this error: Failed caused by: can't set attribute